# Function that is continuous only on the transcendental numbers

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Recently I saw Thomae's Function, also called the Popcorn Function, which is continuous at the irrationals and discontinuous at the rationals.

This made me wonder: is there a function which is continuous at every transcendental number and discontinuous at every algebraic number?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, the idea behind Thomae's function easily generalizes to any countable set.  Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ be any countable set and let $i:S\to\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ be an injection (or more generally, any finite-to-one function).  Define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x\not\in S$ and $f(x)=1/i(x)$ if $x\in S$.  Then $f$ is continuous at a point $x\in\mathbb{R}$ iff $x\not\in S$ (the proof is very similar to that for Thomae's function).

More generally, it can in fact be shown that a subset $S\subset\mathbb{R}$ is the points of discontinuity of some function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ iff it is $F_\sigma$ (i.e., a countable union of closed sets).

Comment: +1. Just for completeness, the set of discontinuities of a function is *always* $F_\sigma$, so that's a complete characterization.

Comment: Eric Wofsey Can you help [Connection of complex $e^z$ and real Dirichlet](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2867643/) please?